# Spring MVC Rest: How to implement partial response in Json and XML?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson, xstream

I need to the ignore the serialization (JSon/Jackson and XML/XStream) of some attributes from my object response based on user input/or Spring security roles (like you don't have permission to see the content of this field, but all others are ok etc). How is the best approach to do this in Spring MVC Rest? 
Other approach is show only the attributes that are relevant for the api user, like described here http://googlecode.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/making-apis-faster-introducing-partial.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jackson, here are some possible options to modify the Json serialization:

1. Use the [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) annotation - However, this is static filtering, and will not allow you to implement rule-based filtering as you appear to need
2. Use [@JsonFilter](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) - This will allow you to implement an interface in which you can provide your serialization filtering logic. You may find this to be too heavyweight of a solution.
3. The way I often solve this is to return a Map from my Controller methods instead of the underlying object. You can write processing code that puts the relevant fields from the object into the Map, therefore giving you complete control over what is serialized. You could include a method on the Object to do the conversion. The method could look something like this:

   ```
   // RequestObj is whatever 'input' object that indicates what should be filtered
   public Map<String,Object> convertToMapForRequest(RequestObj request){
       // Build return map based on 'this' and request
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @matt, but this approach only works for JSon and not XML output, and returning a Map<String, Object> it is too abstract and doing that I will lose the semantics of return. I will keep looking for a better solution and let you know.

Comment: for now I put an annotation in my classes 
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
public class MyClass {}
and set the values that I don't like print to Null. (the default xml behavior in Spring is not print null values)

Comment: @wandi.darko did you ever find a good way to do this? I've been looking for a good way, other than the  Yoga https://github.com/skyscreamer/yoga library, i haven't found anything viable.